# SharePoint 2007 public override ToolPart[] GetToolParts() bug?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, content-query-web-part, toolpart

In this Custom Content Query Web Part the following code works. I'm able to change the Web Part title and the ToolPart Title:

```
public class CustomWebPart1 : ContentByQueryWebPart
{
    public override ToolPart[] GetToolParts()
    {
        ToolPart[] toolPartArray = base.GetToolParts();
        return new ToolPart[] { new CustomContentQueryWebPartToolPart(), toolPartArray[0], toolPartArray[1] };
    }
}

public class CustomContentQueryWebPartToolPart : ToolPart
{
    TextBox txt1;
    CustomWebPart1 wp;

    public CustomContentQueryWebPartToolPart()
    {
        this.Title = "My Custom Properties";
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        txt1 = new TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(txt1);

        base.CreateChildControls();
    }

    public override void ApplyChanges()
    {
        this.Title = "ToolPart Title: " + txt1.Text;

        wp = this.WebPartToEdit as CustomWebPart1;

        wp.Title = "WebPart Title: " + txt1.Text;

        base.ApplyChanges();
    }
}
```

[image]

But if i change the position in the array (which is the display order of the web part properties) changing the Web Part title doesn't work anymore!

```
    public override ToolPart[] GetToolParts()
    {
        ToolPart[] toolPartArray = base.GetToolParts();
        return new ToolPart[] { toolPartArray[0], toolPartArray[1], new CustomContentQueryWebPartToolPart() };
    }
```

[image]

What's wrong here? Is this a bug? Changing the ToolPart Title still works.